# C# How to calculate the sum of two number using a SOAP API Service?

Tags: c#, api, soap

I have an application written in C# that calls a SOAP Service for Calculating variables; The variables are entered into two respective text-fields and upon clicking the submit button, the sum should be returned via a label (The label is set to zero). But, when the button is clicked, the application fails to calculate the sum, thus the label remains 0 as oppose to the sum of the two numbers that are entered into the text-fields.

Here is the code:

```
protected void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Calculator.CalculatorSoapClient client = new Calculator.CalculatorSoapClient();

            int intNumOne = int.Parse(txtNumberOne.Text);
            int intNumTwo = int.Parse(txtNumberTwo.Text);

            int SumOfNumbers = client.Add(intNumOne, intNumTwo);

            //convert text to int
            SumOfNumbers = int.Parse(lblResult.Text);


        }
```

this is the reference for client.Add:

```
public int Add(int intA, int intB) {
            return base.Channel.Add(intA, intB);
        }
```

...I'm wondering is my approach for converting the text-fields and label from string to int is the issue. Could I get some help as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you debug it? What are the values of `intNumOne` and `intNumTwo`? What does `client.Add()` look like?

Comment: Also this line seems backwards: `SumOfNumbers = int.Parse(lblResult.Text);`. Shouldn't you be setting the label Text using `SumOfNumbers`?

Comment: @devNull ...during debugging, both intNumOne (value returned is 10 -the number I entered into textfield 1-) and intNumtwo (value returned is 20 - the number I entered in text-field 2), respectively sumOfNumber renders 30, which is correct, but for some reason the label still reflects 0. ...client.Add() is the REST service: http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?op=Add ...Hopefully this makes sense

Comment: @devNull ...also, I added the reference/definition for client.Add() ...let me know please if you can provide further assistance. ...thanks